# What are the rgb values of Arch Linux's console font theme?

Tags: arch-linux

The standard font theme of Arch is great and I'd like to use it for my X environment. I can't figure out how to obtain the rgb values. There are resources on console colors in Arch and linux in general, like the [Arch wiki on color output in console](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Color_output_in_console). I haven't found anything on finding the actual rgb-values, however.

What are the rgb values for the classic Arch font theme?

Comment: Looking at the console, it seems Arch doesn't *customize* the color palette, so the "classic" colors are just those compiled into the Linux kernel.

Comment: Really, I always associated that palette with Arch. After some investigation, https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/tty/vt/vt.c#L1031 seems to be responsible for setting the colors. But I can't find any definition of colors.